# AVERAGEIFS with 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to find the average value - if it's in the correct location and is within acceptable range of categories

This is what I have tried:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Range to average, Criteria range1, Criteria1, Criteria range2, Criteria2)
```

Criteria range1 = categories
Criteria1 = acceptable range of categories (18 out of 27 for example)

Criteria range 2 = locations
Criteria 2 = acceptable location

My code:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!F7:F2403, 'Sheet2'!U7:U2732, Sheet1!A11:A29, 'Sheet3 '!AL7:AL2732, Sheet1!F13)
```

receiving error `#VALUE!`

Not sure what else I can try?

Comment: If you look at Excel help you'll see that "in AVERAGEIFS each criteria_range must be the same size and shape as sum_range."

Comment: Also how can your criteria be a range of cells?

Comment: With countif my criteria as a range of cells works great, altering size and shape of ranges to be the same hasn't helped I'm afraid but hank you for the input

Comment: Criteria in `AVERAGEIFS` is a boolean AND operator and therefor can NOT accept more criteria. So only altering ranges to be the same won't be enough. Can you include sample data, a screenshot perhaps with input expected output. So we can see what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

Your ranges should be the same height and your values should be just one cell. Though this isn't always the case, I am almost certain for your purposes it is necessary.

Generally you will average a set of numbers in a column. If you then want to restrict which rows are included in the average depending on another column, you use that column in an AVERAGEIFS function along with the value you want to use to restrict in the third parameter.

You can then include further range/value pairs if you want, but to start I'd get the initial single column filter working, and then you'll get the idea.

It is very unusual to do an AVERAGEIFS on ranges on different sheets. Gather all of the relevant data into one rectangle of cells, and then experiment with the AVERAGEIFS  function.